# Understanding request.POST receive time in django

Tags: django, post, file-upload, django-rest-framework, request

I am currently facing an issue regarding the exact time of the data received by django post method. Can anyone tell me when the post method starts for receiving file from client side in django? Like does the method starts when the first byte of file is received or after the whole file is finished receiving? I am talking about large file like 3-7 MB sized image. 
And I have the same question for django rest framework. Cause in rest framework I have found that calling as api from android app it takes a lot of time to response like about 6 to sometimes even 30 sec. Whereas the same file is taking 0.01-0.08 sec for normal django view function.

Comment: When uploading files, the wsgi process will "stream" the file to Django and depending on the file size, Django will hold the file in memory or on disk. By default a file larger than 2MB will be stored to disk in a temporary folder (you can change this limit in settings). When your view is running, the file has already been fully uploaded (i.e. your view is called once the entire file has been received), so when you access `request.FILES` the upload process is finished.

Comment: @dirkgroten , Thank you for clearing this.

Comment: But I have found something interesting in drf. I have logged 3 timestamp in my view function. one as the first line of the post function so that I can get the exact time when this starts, another after the request.body["image"] is called and finally before returning from function. Also I tracked the profiler of app from where the api is called and found that the timestamp when the data sending is started and the first timestamp is similar and the timestamp when the full data is sent is similar to the second one. that means the post function is called when the first bit of data is received.

Comment: This is the rest of the previous comment: that means the post function is called when the first bit of data is received. But I can't access request.data until full data is passed. Is it expected behaviour that post function starts when the first bit of data is received? Thanks is advance for your time @dirkgroten .